# How to get a list of RBD Code/ CoS mapping to Cabins for an airline?

Tags: airlines

I'm trying to put some RBD  codes into ITA matrix and look for a flight in a particular RBD code. My problem is that I can't seem to find a list of RBD Code to Cabin mapping for an airline for a specific routes. If I could get a list of all the RBDs for an airline, I'm hoping to search for the RBD which is the cheapest in the cabin that I'm trying to book a seat on.

Is it possible/Would this logic work?

Comment: Seeing as how RBD codes are internal corporate data, why would they be made public for consumers to use?

Comment: What is RBD/CoS?

Comment: @JonathanReez Requested Booking Designator, which is how the Class of Service is recorded in a reservation.

Comment: Incidentally, RBD almost always corresponds to the fare class. Are you trying to find, e.g. *UP fares? Otherwise, wouldn't a search on price and cabin be sufficient?

Comment: What's you ultimate goal here?  You'd also have to factor what you'd be allowed to book as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to book some up fares/ would like to get the cheapest business class if YUP is not available. So I was wondering whether I can look for the cheapest RBDs in business and try to book under it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no publicised source for these that I am aware of. I know that in Amadeus if you perform a MasterPricer search they return the original RBDs along with the mapping to Cabin Classes for the fares that are returned, so the database can be built up this way. If you have access to a GDS then you can likely get this information out of there.

If you need this for just one Airline then I'm happy to submit them on here, if you need it general then you will need to get this out of a GDS or collect individually from each airline.

For EK/EY:

```
RBD AirlineCode CabinClass
A   EK  First
B   EK  Economy
C   EK  Business
D   EK  Business
E   EK  Economy
F   EK  First
G   EK  Economy
H   EK  Economy
I   EK  Business
J   EK  Business
K   EK  Economy
L   EK  Economy
M   EK  Economy
N   EK  Economy
O   EK  Business
P   EK  Business
Q   EK  Economy
R   EK  Economy
S   EK  Economy
T   EK  Economy
U   EK  Economy
V   EK  Economy
W   EK  Economy
X   EK  Economy
Y   EK  Economy
Z   EK  First
A   EY  First
B   EY  Economy
C   EY  Business
D   EY  Business
E   EY  Economy
F   EY  First
G   EY  Economy
H   EY  Economy
I   EY  Economy
J   EY  Business
K   EY  Economy
L   EY  Economy
M   EY  Economy
N   EY  Economy
O   EY  Economy
P   EY  Economy
Q   EY  Economy
R   EY  First
S   EY  Economy
T   EY  Economy
U   EY  Economy
V   EY  Economy
W   EY  Business
X   EY  Business
Y   EY  Economy
Z   EY  Business
```

Comment: Specifically looking for EY/EK.

Comment: Updated now. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you. So is Z the cheapest Business on EK?